# Silly question about sampling a function (distribution vs integral representation)

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a stupid question... if i want to sample a continuous function i can use the Dirac delta distribution

$$f(x_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(x - x_0) f(x)dx,$$

which indeed involves the distribution theory, however i've been thinking that the same thing (with some assumption) could be written as:

$$ f(x_0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi j} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z - x_0} dz$$

where $\gamma$ is a closed curve that contains $x_0$. Is there some relevant relention/difference between the two representations? Could the Cauchy integral formula be seen as a linear functional (like the one usually studied in functional analysis)?

Comment: I don't think that the second representation is valid on a reasonable class of functions. In particular, the values of $f$ on $\gamma$ do not relate to the value $f(x_0)$.

Comment: What do you mean? to me $\gamma$ is "equivalent"/similar to the compact support of a function.

Comment: However i think it is fair to say that at least the representations are similar somehow.

Comment: Maybe I wanted to say the following: If $f$ as a compact support, $\gamma$ is outside if this support, but $f(x_0) \ne 0$, then the second representation does not hold.

Comment: I'd say it can be, but on a rather special space of functions.